# How to find the nth term of a generating function using sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, maxima

I have a rational function: `f(x) = P(x)/Q(x)`.
For example:

```
f(x) = (5x + 3)/(1-x^2)
```

Because f(x) is a generating function it can be written as:

```
f(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x² + ... + a_n*x^n + ... = P(x)/Q(x)
```

How can I use sympy to find the n<sup>th</sup> term of the generating function `f(x)` (that is `a_n`)?

If there is no such implementation in Sympy, I am curious also to know if this implemented in other packages, such as Maxima.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422538/how-to-solve-an-algebraic-equation-in-formal-power-series ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the general formula for `a_n` of the generating function of a rational form , SymPy's [`rational_algorithm`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/formal.html#rational-algorithm) can be used.
For example:

```py
from sympy import simplify
from sympy.abc import x, n
from sympy.series.formal import rational_algorithm

f = (5*x + 3)/(1-x**2)
func_n, independent_term, order = rational_algorithm(f, x, n, full=True)
print(f"The general formula for a_n is {func_n}")
for k in range(10):
    print(f"a_{k} = {simplify(func_n.subs(n, k))}")
```

Output:

```
The general formula for a_n is (-1)**(-n - 1) + 4
a_0 = 3
a_1 = 5
a_2 = 3
a_3 = 5
a_4 = 3
a_5 = 5
a_6 = 3
a_7 = 5
a_8 = 3
a_9 = 5
```

Here is another example:

```py
f = x / (1 - x - 2 * x ** 2)
func_n, independent_term, order = rational_algorithm(f, x, n, full=True)
print(f"The general formula for a_n is {func_n.simplify()}")
print("First terms:", [simplify(func_n.subs(n, k)) for k in range(20)])
```

```
The general formula for a_n is 2**n/3 - (-1)**(-n)/3
First terms: [0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43, 85, 171, 341, 683, 1365, 2731, 5461, 10923, 21845, 43691, 87381, 174763]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could take the kth derivative and substitute 0 for `x` and divide by `factorial(k)`:

```
>>> f = (5*x + 3) / (1-x**2)
>>> f.diff(x, 20).subs(x, 0)/factorial(20)
3
```

The reference [here](http://jaypantone.com/courses/winter16math118/lecture-notes/lecture-notes-07.pdf) talks about rational generating functions. Looking for a recurrence you can see the pattern pretty quickly using differentiation:

```
[f.diff(x,i).subs(x,0)/factorial(i) for i in range(6)]
[3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the approach of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422538/how-to-solve-an-algebraic-equation-in-formal-power-series), you could try the following:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x

f = (5*x + 3) / (1-x**2)
print(f.series(n=20))
k = 50
coeff50 = Poly(series(f, x, n=k + 1).removeO(), x).coeff_monomial(x ** k)
print(f"The coeffcient of x^{k} of the generating function of {f} is {coeff50}")

# to get the first 100 coeffcients (reversing the list to get a[0] the
#   coefficient of x**0 etc.):
a = Poly(series(f, x, n=100).removeO(), x).all_coeffs()[::-1]
```

Output:

```
3 + 5*x + 3*x**2 + 5*x**3 + 3*x**4 + 5*x**5 + 3*x**6 + 5*x**7 + 3*x**8 + 5*x**9 + 3*x**10 + 5*x**11 + 3*x**12 + 5*x**13 + 3*x**14 + 5*x**15 + 3*x**16 + 5*x**17 + 3*x**18 + 5*x**19 + O(x**20)
The coeffcient of x^50 of the generating function of (5*x + 3)/(1 - x**2) is 3
```

Following [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/GeneratingFunctions.shtml) example at Cut The Knot, the approach can be used to find out the number of ways an amount `n` can be paid with coins of 1, 5, 10, 25 and 50 cents.

```
f = 1/((1 - x)*(1 - x**5)*(1 - x**10)*(1 - x**25)*(1 - x**50))
a = Poly(series(f, x, n=101).removeO(), x).all_coeffs()[::-1]
print(a[50]) # there are 50 ways to pay 50 cents
print(a[100]) # there are 292 ways to pay 100 cents
```

Answer (score 0):

In maxima:

```
powerseries((5*x+3)/(1-x^2),x,0);
```

returns

[image: powerseries_maxima_result]

Use `part` to extract the generator:

```
part(''%,1);
(4-(-1)^i1)x^i1
```

and `coeff` to get the coefficient:

```
a(i1) := coeff(''%, x, i1);
[a(0), a(1), a(2)];
[3, 5, 3]
```

Comment: How to return only the coefficient `a_n`?

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to approach this is to use the ring series:

```
>>> from sympy.polys.ring_series import rs_mul, rs_pow
>>> from sympy.polys.rings import ring
>>> R,x=ring('x', ZZ)
>>> from sympy import ZZ
>>> R,x=ring('x', ZZ)
>>> nmax = 100
>>> s = rs_mul(5*x+3, rs_pow(1-x**2, -1, x, nmax+1), x, nmax+1)
>>> [s.coeff(x**i) for i in (2,3,5,17,100)]
[3, 5, 5, 5, 3]
```